# Passing custom tailwind config file to postcss loader

Tags: webpack, tailwind-css, postcss, postcss-loader

In my project I want to generate 2 tailwind files.

1. Frontend file, no prefixes
2. Admin file, all classes prefixed

I have added 2 config files:

- tailwind.config.js
- tailwind.admin.config.js

Inside `tailwind.admin.config.js` I have added the property:

`prefix: 'tw-',`

The problem is in webpack I am unable to specify the alternative config inside my rule.  No matter what I do it always uses the `tailwind.config.js` file.

Here is my webpack rule for the amdin file:

```js
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        },
        {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
                importLoaders: 1,
            }
        },
        {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
                postcssOptions: {
                    plugins: [
                        require('precss'),
                        require('tailwindcss')('./tailwind.admin.config.js'),
                        require('autoprefixer'),
                    ]
                }

            },
        }
    ],
},
```

the format `require('tailwindcss')('./tailwind.admin.config.js'),` is only one I have seen for specifying the config file but it is not working inside `postcss-loader`.  It always uses default file instead.

How do I specify the exact tailwind config to use inside webpack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that if you have any file named as derfault config file it will always use them no matter what you do.  Renaming the default files to something else made it actually take the file I was passing it.